# Does Geometry by expression in QGIS except layer without geometry?

Tags: qgis, geojson, vector, distance-matrix, geometry-generator

There is distance matrix with 9.455 features without geometries in GeoJSON format. It was created outside of QGIS with a tool similar to QGIS's "Distance matrix".

The matrix looks like this:

[image: input]

Now I am trying to connect these features with points from/to that have geometries and stored in other layers.

I am doing it with ["Geometry by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression), where I take my matrix as an *'Input layer'*

[image: window]

and I am using this expression to create a line:

```
make_line(
    geometry(
        get_feature(
            'layer_from',
            'fid',
            "FROM_ID"
            )
        ), 
    geometry(
        get_feature(
            'layer_to',
            'fid',
            "TO_ID"
            )
        )
    )
```

When I press <kbd>Run</kbd> I receive an empty output. Why?

I wrapped the above expression into `is_empty_or_null(...)` and I got `false` -> means that geometries are not `NULL`, they exist somewhere.

When I read [the documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#id106) it says that input layer is a vector layer:

```
INPUT: Input layer

Parameter type: QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource

Accepted data types:
    - str: layer ID
    - str: layer name
    - str: layer source
    - QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition
    - QgsProperty
    - QgsVectorLayer
```

This is logical. Moreover, when I checked the 'Matrix' layer with some PyQGIS:

```py
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Matrix')[0]

print(layer.type()) # QgsMapLayerType.VectorLayer
print(layer.LayerType) # <enum 'QgsMapLayerType'>
print(layer.PropertyType) # <class 'qgis._core.QgsMapLayer.PropertyType'>
print(layer.geometryType()) # 4
print(layer.providerType()) # ogr
print(layer.storageType()) # GeoJSON
```

it looks also promising to me, looks like a Vector, is not it?

Are there any workarounds available? Maybe it is not possible at all. And simply saying "Geometry by expression" in QGIS does not except layer without geometry as an input.

The one that I found is to refer to layer with *destination*-points via 'Matrix' layer, taking *origin*-points as an *'Input'* in the "Geometry by expression".

Perhaps it is again the same story, that:

> QGIS does not support `GeometryCollection` as a valid geometry type.

which is inside of my GeoJSON:

[image: geojson]

BTW, this is a piece of GeoJSON that I am working on:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "Matrix",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "FROM_ID": 1, "TO_ID": 1, "DURATION_H": 0.92035555555555559, "DIST_KM": 4.60184 }, "geometry": null },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "FROM_ID": 1, "TO_ID": 2, "DURATION_H": 1.1758277777777777, "DIST_KM": 5.87926 }, "geometry": null },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "FROM_ID": 1, "TO_ID": 3, "DURATION_H": 1.5567583333333332, "DIST_KM": 7.7839 }, "geometry": null },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "FROM_ID": 1, "TO_ID": 4, "DURATION_H": 1.5678055555555557, "DIST_KM": 7.83914 }, "geometry": null },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "FROM_ID": 1, "TO_ID": 5, "DURATION_H": 0.44944166666666668, "DIST_KM": 2.24724 }, "geometry": null },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "FROM_ID": 1, "TO_ID": 6, "DURATION_H": 0.41768055555555555, "DIST_KM": 2.08844 }, "geometry": null },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "FROM_ID": 1, "TO_ID": 7, "DURATION_H": 1.156236111111111, "DIST_KM": 5.78126 }, "geometry": null },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "FROM_ID": 1, "TO_ID": 8, "DURATION_H": 1.2599444444444445, "DIST_KM": 6.2998 }, "geometry": null },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "FROM_ID": 1, "TO_ID": 9, "DURATION_H": 1.1397833333333334, "DIST_KM": 5.69899 }, "geometry": null },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "FROM_ID": 1, "TO_ID": 10, "DURATION_H": 0.60408888888888879, "DIST_KM": 3.02048 }, "geometry": null }
]
}
```

Comment: And no Virtual Layers this time ? You can do it so easily with !

Comment: @J.Monticolo yes, I know how to. But imho it is not an efficient when the data is big.

Comment: So virtual layer is slower than expressions? This question is still unanswered: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/382520/88814

Comment: @Babel, I think the expression Tag is redundant here. It is more about data input and geo algorithm itself

Comment: OK, feel free to remove it if you think it is not appropriate here.

Comment: You can create a Polyline layer without geometry, have the attributes of the JSON and directly update the field *geometry* with your expression.

Comment: @J.Monticolo, sounds like a task for PyQGIS ☺️

Comment: You can do it directly under QGIS, unless you have a lot of files to process, but here it's more like a DB task than a Python task, maybe Geopandas to update the entire dataframe ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The problem**

The problem with your expression is that you apply it on the `Matrix` layer, but this is a layer without geometry. Creating geometries works only on layers that contain geomtries. It does not even work on a geometry layer that does not contain any features (empty layer).

I think Geometry generator (and by extension Geometry by expression) is a way to style (visualize) geometries - however, when you do not have any geometries, you can't style anything. In your case, you have an "attribute only" layer. I don't know why this is considered to be a vector, maybe vector in the sense that it's not a raster layer. It's data structure (a layer with an attribute table) is closer to a vector then a raster layer.

**How to solve it**

So the expression must be based on one of the point layers that you want to connect. Here I used the `layer_from`.

Use this expression:

```
collect_geometries( 
    array_foreach (
        generate_series (0,  aggregate( 'matrix', 'count', $id)-1),
        make_line(
            geometry(
                get_feature(
                    'layer_from',
                    'fid',
                    attribute (
                        get_feature_by_id (
                            'matrix',
                            @element
                        ),
                    'FROM_ID'
                    )
                )
            ), 
            geometry(
                get_feature(
                    'layer_to',
                    'fid',
                    attribute (
                        get_feature_by_id (
                            'matrix',
                            @element
                        ),
                    'TO_ID'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

[image]